# Equivalence Relation on points of a Projective Variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be a projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$. Let $x,y \in X(k)$, call $x \sim y$ iff there exists a map $f : \mathbb{P}^1_k \rightarrow X$ such that $x,y \in f(\mathbb{P}^1_k)$.

Is the above relation an equivalence relation on $X(k)$? If not what would be a counterexample?

Comment: is there any restriction on $f$? what does $g$ stand for? and finally, did you mean $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{K}}$?

Comment: @JayTuma I have edited the question appropriately. I do not impose any restrictions on the morphism $f$.

Comment: I think in general, transitivity can fail. Think of blowing up points on, say an abelian surface, then you can have two rational curves $L, M$ meeting at a point, say $P$. Then points on $L$ are related to $P$ and same for $M$, but points other than $P$ one on $L$, another on $M$ are not related.That is why the relation `linearly connected', allowing several rational curves in $X$ is better.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks! That works as a counterexample. Are there some more conditions one can put so that the above relation is an equivalence relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just posting Mohan's comment here so as to close this question.

"I think in general, transitivity can fail. Think of blowing up points on, say an abelian surface, then you can have two rational curves $L,M$ meeting at a point, say $P$. Then points on $L$ are related to $P$ and same for $M$, but points other than $P$ one on $L$, another on $M$ are not related.That is why the relation `linearly connected', allowing several rational curves in X is better." – Mohan